# Install Reporting Services 2K8R2 on W2K8R2 Cluster Nodes

Tags: sql-server, cluster, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs, ssrs-2008-r2

First I'm aware that Reporting Services is not Cluster aware, But I would like to install it on my each node of my 2 node Cluster on the default instance.

I've got the following error installing

> Rule Check Result
>
> Rule "Existing clustered or
> cluster-prepared instance" failed.
>
> The instance selected for installation
> is already installed and clustered on
> computer SQL-1. To continue, select
> a different instance to cluster.
>
> OK

Is there a way to install it without a named instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've e-mailed the writers of the pss sql blog (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/) and they've explained that you can't change a SQL Cluster installation after it has been done, and there are two ways of installing SSRS on the cluster node machines (Again SSRS is not cluster aware, it scales out), so the first one is installing it on a named instance, and the other one is unninstalling the clustered sql node, and then installing it with Reporting Services, however through the e-mails they convinced me that the named instance was a better solution, as for having SSRS on the default instance can cause confusion as SSRS not being Cluster aware.
So I installed SSRS 2008 R2 on both cluster nodes as a named instance, then I changed the Url, joined them both on farms and was all set up.

Thanks PSS Team. (specially Adam Saxton)